# Disable a button if row is selected in MudBlazor Table

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

I'm trying to disable a button if no row is selected in a MudTable, so I'm trying to do something like the following.

```
Disabled=(selectedRow is null)
```

How would I do this properly?

Comment: There are several ways to achieve this: you must first consider if you want to handle @onclick definition in your condition, because it is easy to remove manually `disabled` from a button.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.SelectedItem` property of the MudTable.

```
<MudTable @ref="mudTable">
    <!-- other table stuff inside here -->
</MudTable>

<button disabled="@(mudTable.SelectedItem == null)" 
        @onclick="DoSomething">Click Here</button>
```